# RadioButton Listener inside a DialogFragment

Tags: android, radio-button, listener

I've try to implement RadioGroup view and put it inside a DialogFragment, but something gone wrong. I've follow this tutorial

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

but instead Activity, view is initialized in a DialogFragment:

```
public class MenuDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public MenuDialog(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, container);
        this.getDialog().setTitle("title");
        return view;
    }

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio1:
        if(checked) {
            Log.i("MENU", ((RadioButton)view).getText());
        }
        break;
    case R.id.radio2:
        if(checked) {
            Log.i("MENU", ((RadioButton)view).getText());
        }
        break;
    case R.id.radio3:
        if(checked) {
            Log.i("MENU", ((RadioButton)view).getText());
        }
        break;
    case R.id.radio4:
        if(checked) {
            Log.i("MENU", ((RadioButton)view).getText());
        }
        break;
    }
    this.getDialog().dismiss();
}
```

}

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:text="20" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:text="40" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:text="60" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:text="80" />
</RadioGroup>
```

onRadioButtonClicked listener it's implemented in the same way of tutorial. Now, when launch dialog, if i tap on a radiobutton i obtain this error:

```
09-27 09:41:08.018: E/AndroidRuntime(7447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 09:41:08.018: E/AndroidRuntime(7447): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
 find a method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in the activity class 
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class 
android.widget.RadioButton with id 'radio1'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: then how the listener is implemented, the problem is the listener is not found, post your listener and xml please

Comment: post modified with missing code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather implement the click handler inside of the fragment and add the listener dynamically (via java instead of XML).
So I would do something like this:

```
public class MenuDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener{
[...]    
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, container);
    view.findViewById(R.id.radio1).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.radio2).setOnClickListener(this);
    //and so on [...]
    this.getDialog().setTitle("title");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Or use the OnCheckedChangeListener instead OnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you specify [`onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick) callback attribute for any `View` in xml file it should be located inside an `Activity` code but not in fragment code

Comment: so i need to modify onCreateView code and manually add a listener?

Comment: If you want to associate onClick callback with view directly from fragment then, yes, you should set OnClickListener from fragment's `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the listener with the radio group, you can do it this way

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, container);
    this.getDialog().setTitle("title");
    view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group).setOnCheckedChangeListener(...);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener for your fragment. setOnCheckedChangeListener according to your radio buttons.

```
public class MenuDialog extends DialogFragment implements RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

//..

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, container);
    this.getDialog().setTitle("title");

    ((RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio1)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    ((RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio2)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    // and so on

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean checked) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio1: 
            // todo
            break;
        case R.id.radio2: 
            // todo
            break;
        // and so on.. 
    }
    this.getDialog().dismiss();
}
```

BTW remove onRadioButtonClicked() in your fragment and "android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"" for the RadioButton in xml as you follow the instruction from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am a little bit late, but discovered this solution. Works on API 23

**YourDialogFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return requireActivity().let {
        AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            .setTitle("Your title here")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(
               R.array.answersStringAray, // resource in res/values/arrays.xml
               1, // value of choosed item in array above 
               clickListener // Implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
            )
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, clickListener)
            .create()
    }
}
```

**YourViewModel.kt**

```
class YourViewModel : ViewModel(), DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
        when (which) {
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> {}
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE -> {}
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL -> {}
            0 -> {} // all your answers would be non-negative
            1 -> {}
        }
    }
}
```